# Converting uppercase to lowercase, program won't print out entire string

Tags: c++, xcode, string

I tried to create a code that converts all uppercase characters into lowercase from a string.

However at the end when I print out the converted string, the whole string won't print out. For example, I will input "Hello This Is My String" and the program will only print out "hello" before exiting.

Can anyone help me find out what went wrong? Thank you so much in advance. I am using Xcode for reference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    char z[100];
    int i;
    cout << "Enter a string: \n";
    cin >> z;
    for (i=0; i< strlen(z); i++)
    {
        if (z[i] >= 65 && z[i] <= 90)
        {
            z[i]=z[i] + 32;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n New string in lowercase = " << z;
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint after the `cin` line, and inspect the value of z. Is it what you expected?

Comment: it works fine. if you want white spaces then use getline

Comment: Prefer to use character constants rather than their ASCII codes.  Like 'A' instead of 65.

Comment: To *burst your bubble*, take a look at the functions `std::tolower` and `std::toupper`.  With a little more research, you could find `std::string` and `std::transform`.

Comment: I don't understand.  You include `<string>`, but you don't use the `std::string` type.  You use `strlen`, but don't have an include for it.  The `strlen` is located in `cstring` for C++.